# One checkbox triggering another checkbox in a different layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm currently writing an app that displays a list of movies. I have many fragments that display a cardview containing movies, and each cardview has a checkbox. The user can press on the cardview to go to the details page of the movie where another checkbox is present.

The goal of both checkboxes is to add the movie to the favorites tab.

My question is, how can I make the checkbox that is inside the details page checked when the user checks the one in the cardview?

Below is the relevant code.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

MoviesListFragment.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.ui.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import androidx.core.view.isGone
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.moviesapp.R
import com.example.moviesapp.databinding.FragmentMoviesListBinding
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesFavorites
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesResults
import com.example.moviesapp.ui.DaoViewModel
import com.example.moviesapp.ui.MovieApiStatus
import com.example.moviesapp.ui.MoviesListAdapter
import com.example.moviesapp.ui.MoviesListViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MoviesListFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_movies_list), MoviesListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies_list, container, false)
    }



    private val daoViewModel by viewModels<DaoViewModel>()
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MoviesListViewModel>()
    private var _binding: FragmentMoviesListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!




    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //View is inflated layout

        _binding = FragmentMoviesListBinding.bind(view)

        val adapter = MoviesListAdapter(this)


        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            //Disable animations
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter


        }

        //Observe the movies livedata
        //Use viewLifecycleOwner instead of this because the UI should stop being updated when the fragment view is destroyed
        viewModel.getTrending()

       viewModel.moviesTrending.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           adapter.submitList(it)

       }

        viewModel.networkState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = if (it==MovieApiStatus.LOADING) true else view.isGone
            binding.buttonRetry.isVisible = if(it==MovieApiStatus.ERROR) true else view.isGone
            binding.errorTextView.isVisible = if(it==MovieApiStatus.ERROR) true else view.isGone
            binding.recyclerView.isVisible =  if(it==MovieApiStatus.DONE) true else view.isGone
            binding.noResultsText.isVisible = false


        })









        //Display trending movies

        //loadstate is of type combined loadstates, which combines the loadstate of different scenarios(when we refresh dataset or when we append new data to it) into this one object
        //We can use it to check for these scenarios and make our views visible or unvisible according to it

       setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun  onItemClick(movie: MoviesResults.Movies) {
        val action = MoviesListFragmentDirections.actionMoviesListFragmentToMoviesDetailsFragment(movie)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }

    override fun onFavoriteClick(favorites: MoviesFavorites) {
        daoViewModel.addMovieToFavs(favorites)
    }

    override fun onDeleteClick(favorites: MoviesFavorites) {
        daoViewModel.deleteMovieFromFavs(favorites)
    }






    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)

        // Inflate the gallery menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_gallery, menu)




    }





    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

MoviesListAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.ui

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.moviesapp.R
import com.example.moviesapp.databinding.MovieLayoutBinding
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesFavorites
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesResults

val IMAGE_BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"

class MoviesListAdapter constructor(private val listener: OnItemClickListener) :
     ListAdapter<MoviesResults.Movies, MoviesListAdapter.MoviesListViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    private lateinit var fav: MoviesFavorites





    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MoviesListViewHolder {
        val binding = MovieLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)


        return MoviesListViewHolder(binding)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MoviesListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)

        holder.binding.favoritesCheckbox.isChecked = currentItem.isFavorite
        holder.binding.favoritesCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            currentItem.isFavorite

        }

        if(holder.binding.favoritesCheckbox.isChecked ) {
            currentItem.isFavorite = true

        }


        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.bind(currentItem)

        }







    }

    inner class MoviesListViewHolder(val binding: MovieLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {




        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    val item = getItem(position)
                    listener.onItemClick(item)
                }
            }
        }

        init {

            binding.favoritesCheckbox.setOnClickListener{

                if(binding.favoritesCheckbox.isChecked) {

                    val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val item = getItem(position)
                        item.isFavorite = true
                        fav = MoviesFavorites(item.title, item.id, item.release_date, item.overview, item.vote_average, item.poster_path, item.original_language, item.isFavorite)
                        listener.onFavoriteClick(fav)
                        listener.onCheckboxClick(binding.favoritesCheckbox.isChecked)

                    }

                    showToast("${fav.title} is added to your favorites")





                }
                else {
                    val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val item = getItem(position)
                        item.isFavorite = false
                         fav = MoviesFavorites(item.title, item.id, item.release_date, item.overview, item.vote_average, item.poster_path, item.original_language, item.isFavorite)
                        listener.onDeleteClick(fav)
                        listener.onCheckboxClick(binding.favoritesCheckbox.isChecked)
                    }


                    showToast("${fav.title} is removed from your favorites")
                }

            }



        }



        fun bind(movie: MoviesResults.Movies) {
            binding.apply {
                movieTitle.text = movie.title
                movieRating.text = movie.vote_average
                movieYear.text = movie.release_date
                Glide.with(itemView)
                    .load(IMAGE_BASE_URL + movie.poster_path)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_error_outline_24)
                    .into(movieImage)
               val item = getItem(absoluteAdapterPosition)
                favoritesCheckbox.isChecked = item.isFavorite






            }

        }


        private fun showToast(string: String) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.context, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }


    }


    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(movie: MoviesResults.Movies)
        fun onFavoriteClick(favorites: MoviesFavorites)
        fun onDeleteClick(favorites: MoviesFavorites)
        fun onCheckboxClick(fav: Boolean)
    }







    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MoviesResults.Movies>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: MoviesResults.Movies,
            newItem: MoviesResults.Movies
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: MoviesResults.Movies,
            newItem: MoviesResults.Movies
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }


}
```

MoviesDetailsFragment.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.ui.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.moviesapp.R
import com.example.moviesapp.databinding.FragmentMoviesDetailsBinding
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesFavorites
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesResults
import com.example.moviesapp.ui.DaoViewModel
import com.example.moviesapp.ui.IMAGE_BASE_URL
import com.example.moviesapp.ui.SharedViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MoviesDetailsFragment() : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_movies_details) {


    //We can get the movies from the args property
    private val args by navArgs<MoviesDetailsFragmentArgs>()
    private val daoViewModel by viewModels<DaoViewModel>()
    private val sharedViewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>()
    private fun showToast(string: String) {
        Toast.makeText(view?.context, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = FragmentMoviesDetailsBinding.bind(view)


        sharedViewModel.checkBox.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            binding.favCheckbox.isChecked = it

        }



        binding.apply {
            val movie: MoviesResults.Movies = args.movie
            val fav = MoviesFavorites(
                movie.title,
                movie.id,
                movie.release_date,
                movie.overview,
                movie.vote_average,
                movie.poster_path,
                movie.original_language,
                movie.isFavorite,
            )
            //When you are in fragment/activity, pass it to a glide.with because view is less efficient
            Glide.with(this@MoviesDetailsFragment)
                .load(IMAGE_BASE_URL + movie.poster_path)
                //Have the textview visible only when image is visible
                .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_error_outline_24)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(coverPhoto)

            title.text = movie.title
            releaseDate.text = movie.release_date
            language.text = movie.original_language
            rating.text = movie.vote_average
            plot.text = movie.overview





            favCheckbox.setOnClickListener {


                if (favCheckbox.isChecked) {


                    fav.isFavorite = true
                    daoViewModel.addMovieToFavs(fav)
                    showToast("${fav.title} is added to your favorites")

                } else {


                    fav.isFavorite = false
                    daoViewModel.deleteMovieFromFavs(fav)
                    showToast("${fav.title} is removed from your favorites")


                }


            }
        }


    }


}
```

SharedViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.ui

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider



class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {


    val checkBox = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()


    fun sendValue(favorite: Boolean) {
        checkBox.value = favorite

    }

    class SharedViewModelFactor(

    ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(SharedViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return SharedViewModel() as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")

        }


    }








}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user 2 methods to do so:
1 ) You can use `LocalBroadcast` to notify one fragment/activity of change in another.
**Note**: `LocalBroadcast` in now deprecated. Alternatively you can use [eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to communication between fragments

1. Create a local Broadcast

   ```
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // intent can contain anydata
        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive called");
      }
    };
   ```
2. Register your receiver in onResume of fragment like:

   ```
   public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter iff= new IntentFilter(MyIntentService.ACTION);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, iff);
    }
   ```
3. unRegister receiver in onPause:

   ```
    public void onPause() {    
      super.onPause();    
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(onNotice);    
    }
   ```

For more information can you can refer to:
https://blog.mindorks.com/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-android

2 ) You can use `LiveData` to observe data changes of one fragment in another

1. Create shared ViewModel

   ```
   public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {

   private MutableLiveData<String> name;

   public void setNameData(String nameData) {
       name.setValue(nameData);
   }

   public MutableLiveData<String> getNameData() {
       if (name == null) {
           name = new MutableLiveData<>();
       }

       return name;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Fragment One

   ```
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

    public FragmentOne() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {

               sharedViewModel.setNameData(submitText.getText().toString());
              }
         });

    }
   ```
3. Fragment Two

   ```
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

    public FragmentTwo() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        sharedViewModel.getNameData().observe(this, nameObserver);
    }

    Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(String name) {
          receivedText.setText(name);
       }
    };
   ```

For more details on viewmodel you can refer to :

https://nabeelj.medium.com/android-how-to-share-data-between-fragments-using-viewmodel-and-livedata-android-mvvm-9fc463af5152

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragments

Comment: I already have two viewmodels, one for the api and one for the room database. Should I add a third one just for these two fragments?

Comment: Yes you can add third viewmodel as long as you are careful to manage observers for all three.

Comment: But the thing is I can't access the first checkbox since that fragment only has a recyclerview of a layout and that layout has the checkbox

Comment: Give a callback using interface from recycler view adapter to fragment
Hope this helps : https://www.codexpedia.com/android/defining-item-click-listener-for-recyclerview-in-android/

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. I updated the post with the new code, can you take a look at it please?

Comment: You haven't set the update data in viewmodel in MoviesListFragment.kt . 
Also you need to bind shared viewmodel with the lifecycle of Parent activity of both fragments, currently it's bound to fragment lifecycle

Comment: You can refer this github sample  : 
https://github.com/WaheedNazir/Communication-ActivityFragment-ViewModel

Comment: I did set it, I overrode onCheckboxclick

Comment: I think the issue might be with the adapter when I'm calling the method in the interface

Comment: Can you debug and see how are you getting the callback data. Also can you update the code , as I don't see onCheckboxclick() method.

Comment: I found one more alternative solution after looking at your code , you are already saving the favorite movies in the database on the click. onFavoriteClick(). On the details screen create one more database query to fetch and check if movie id has been marked as favourite and update checkbox according.

Comment: I'm still new and I don't how to debug lol. Also I want to add but I can't edit, but in the movieslistfragment I just overrode oncheckboxclick and called the sendvalue method from the viewmodel.

Yeah I am saving the movies in the database but I have another details fragment for the favorites section where I save the same attributes with the checkbox

Comment: Once movie is saved in database on list screen , just fetch if it's saved on details fragment and update  accordingly. Use this to learn about debug process https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-1-get-started/lesson-3-testing,-debugging,-and-using-support-libraries/3-1-c-the-android-studio-debugger/3-1-c-the-android-studio-debugger.html

Comment: How exactly do you mean?

Comment: The way I set up is the list fragment and the other fragments(search results, action movies, comedy movies, etc) lead to the movies details fragment while the favorites fragment leads to another details fragment. The second details fragment is saved via room and the checkbox in it is always checked unless the user unchecks and then it is removed from the favorites

Comment: When on list fragment you save it to database and opens details screen, on details screen run a query to fetch Boolean value from data to check if that movie has been marked as checked. If movie has been checked or not is also being saved in database

Comment: But how will that help with relating the two checkboxes that are not in the favorites?

Comment: You are always adding it to favorites before checkbox click onCheckbozClick(). I don't think second case will matter in this case then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236698/discussion-between-ahmadddd4-and-nitish-chaudhary).