# TextView in Fragment Returning Null in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

i am new to Android Studio.. i am facing null pointer exception error on my TextView inside a Fragment, please help..here is my code. this is nothing but a simple interface between two fragments. i am getting Null pointer exception error when i click on an item in ListView Fragment. for sure the TextView in DetailsFragment didn't assign or point to the source of whatever it is. please help on solving this.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements list_Fragment.ItemSelected {

    ArrayList<String> Descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();;
    TextView tvDescription;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Descriptions.add("Description for Item 1");
        Descriptions.add("Description for Item 2");
        Descriptions.add("Description for Item 3");
        Descriptions.add("Description for Item 4");
        tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int index) {
        tvDescription.setText(Descriptions.get(index));
    }}
```

### list_fragment

```
public class list_Fragment extends ListFragment {

    ArrayList<String> Data = new ArrayList<String>();


    ItemSelected activity;
    public interface ItemSelected{
void onItemSelected(int index);
    }

    public list_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity=(ItemSelected) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Data.add("Item 1");
        Data.add("Item 2");
        Data.add("Item 3");
        Data.add("Item 4");
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Data));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(@NonNull ListView l, @NonNull View v, int position, long id) {

        activity.onItemSelected(position);
    }
}
```

and the details Fragment code, where  i am getting the error i believe, is

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
    }
}
```

### Main XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll_Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/listfragmentView"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentcheck.list_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list_" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/detailsfragmentView"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentcheck.DetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### ListFragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_variant"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".list_Fragment">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### DetailsFragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_on_secondary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailsFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fragmentcheck, PID: 28112
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object r*emphasized text*eference
        at com.example.fragmentcheck.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:34)
        at com.example.fragmentcheck.list_Fragment.onListItemClick(list_Fragment.java:54)
```

Comment: You have `tvDescription` in `DetailsFragment`  xml, while you are finding it's id in `MainAcitvity`. MainActivity just have FragmentContainerView , it doen't have any text view inside it.

Comment: oh okay, Since activity_main is hosting the two fragments inside it, i thought this will naturally inherit the views inside the fragments. you suggest me to assign the TextView to its corresponding R.id in detailsfragment java class? i will try that now.

Comment: No that's not how it works , You can't access fragment view ids in activity , `tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);` use this in your `DetailsFragment` . Also in Details Fragment , you don't need to cast it into LinearLayout

Comment: when i try this, it is now showing " Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'DetailsFragment' ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tvDescription` is in the `DetailsFragment` layout, you need to do any layout configuration in the code for that Class

i.e.

```
class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)
          tvDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
          tvDescription.setText("some text");
       
        return view
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the replay,

Comment: when i try this, it is now showing " Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'DetailsFragment' "

Comment: Hi my mistake, I edited my answer to fix it

Comment: no sir, its not about setting the text. i am having problems with passing tvDescriptions TextView to MainActivity java class, where i want to set text to the TextView according to other arguments that are coming in to some method.  i am still getting the Null Pointer exception in my main class tvDescription.setText(Descriptions.get(index));

Comment: @two yes - if you want the tvDescription TextView to be set in MainActivity then you need to add it to Main.xml OR you need to pass the data from MainActivity to DetailsFragment and set it there. The Data could be passed via Intents or Bundle args

Answer (score 0):

You have `tvDescription` in `DetailsFragment` xml, while you are finding it's id in `MainAcitvity`. MainActivity just have `FragmentContainerView` , it doen't have any text view inside it.

You need to inflate the Fragment's view and call `findViewById()` on the `View` it returns.

**Updated DetailsFragment**

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tvDescription;
    public DetailsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)
          tvDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
          tvDescription.setText("some text");
       
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nitish, i have tried the code above it didn't work. i am still getting the same error, i even tried to pass the tvDescription pointer from DetailsFragment class to main class by adding a return method, still it is not working. : (

Comment: Why are you passing tvDescription from DetailsFragment to MainActivity?  if you want to communication between fragments, use event bus or viewmodel . Refer to this answer for more details - [communcation between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69019046/one-checkbox-triggering-another-checkbox-in-a-different-layout/69024515#69024515)

Answer (score 0):

Change both: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

To: fragment

In the main_activity xml